# How to localize Info.plist content in Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization, info.plist

I have a Xamarin iOS application that supports 4 different languages ​​at the moment. However
I would now like to be able to translate the contents of my info.plist file and its keys like NSCameraUsageDescription so that its
values ​​can be translated as well.

I have done quite a lot of research so far and by searching through the documentation it is advisable to create an InfoPlist.strings file which would contain
my key **NSCameraUsageDescription = "the content here".**

There would be an InfoPlist.strings file for each language and this would be contained in a folder *fr.lproj*, *es.lproj* etc following the language.

I think that it is relatively well explained to exploit this option in Xcode with the possibility to create .strings files and to localize them directly.
However, on Visual Studio I have some difficulties to introduce and adapt my files. The equivalent of a .strings file on Xcode is a .resx file on VS ?

How can the relationship between my InfoPlist.strings and my main Info.plist file be in order to tell my application to tap in the folder fr.lproj / InfoPlist.strings when I switch to french for instance.

Am I supposed to create one folder for each language named fr.lproj where I put a single file InfoPlist.strings or InfoPlist.resx with my keys ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, on Visual Studio I have some difficulties to introduce and
>   adapt my files. The equivalent of a .strings file on Xcode is a .resx
>   file on VS ?

No, to create a `.strings` file in visual studio, you should choose add -> new item -> **Text File**, then change the file name With `xxx.strings`.

> How can the relationship between my InfoPlist.strings and my main
>   Info.plist file be in order to tell my application to tap in the
>   folder fr.lproj / InfoPlist.strings when I switch to french for
>   instance.

If you created the `InfoPlist.strings` for each language, it will automatically read the configuration in the file of the Corresponding language, and then show the right language. If the key was not find on the `InfoPlist.strings`, it will use the default value in main Info.plist.

> Am I supposed to create one folder for each language named fr.lproj
>   where I put a single file InfoPlist.strings or InfoPlist.resx with my
>   keys ?

Yes, if you have four language to support, you should create 3 xx.lporj folders(another is Base.lporj) and each contains an `InfoPlist.strings` and `Localizable.strings.`

In your `InfoPlist.strings` file, set the key `NSCameraUsageDescription` = "the content here" and ect....

Read the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/#localization-basics-in-ios) may help.

Here is what I just created in my project:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear and complete answer, I was able to translate these file properly.